# how to call and sort data in a view?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have two view, one is sorting 2011 data and the other one is sorting the 2012, 
2013 is coming and I think, create another view is not good. Then I tried to code a formula to call the data in my database and send to view but it's not working .

please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to create another view.  Notes doesn't do well with dynamic view selection formulas.

Another alternative to consider is to use categories to group data by year.  You could then set up an embedded view that shows only a single category, which could be determined by a drop-down field that shows the available years.

Comment: sir, i have last question? how can i translate this sql script to lotus script? select * from view there year = "combobox" ? thank sir.

Comment: Notes is nothing like SQL.  You can't just translate a query into LotusScript.  If you want to follow Ken's advice you will need to create a form and put a drop-down field and an embedded view on the form.  Then you can reference the drop-down field value in a formula for the 'show single category' property of the embedded view.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I have used when dealing with weekly or monthly date is to use an agent to create a new folder every week and to put the correct documents in the folder.  But this is a lot of work and if there is a high volume of data you can run into problems with some of the internal limits of the Notes database structure. Someone with expert level knowledge of Notes can probably manage this, but I do not recommend it as a general solution -- and certainly not for yearly data.

Adding a view once a year is really not that bad.  It's two minutes of work every 12 months, just copying and renaming the previous year's view and changing the selection formula.